# SQL update\loop query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some help writing a query.

I have a situation, where I have nearly 400000 records in a database table.

I have to select the 4000000 rows at a time and for every 1000 records I have to update a column with numeric value in a loop.

But that numeric value must increment by one , every 1000 rows.

So an example the first 1000 rows with a numeric value of 1.   Then second 1000 rows with a numeric value of 2.  Repeat that process to all records have a value.

Thank You.

Comment: I was trying to use the row_number() function.  But that increments by one  for every row.

Comment: sql server or mysql?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sql server. Sean ok i amend my post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a total shot in the dark for sql server. No idea if this is the right DBMS or what any of your columns are. But regardless you don't need to use a loop for this sort of thing.

```
with MyCTE as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Something) as RowNum
    from MyTable
)

update MyCTE
set SomeNumberColumn = (RowNum / 1000) + 1
```

Comment: Or you could;   set SomeNumberColumn = RowNum %1000

Comment: @RicardoC that doesn't quite work. They want all values between 1 and 999 to be 1. Consider row 55. 55 % 1000 = 55. Not quite what the OP is looking for. :)

Comment: your answer is strict to what the OP states, yes. But I thought it was irrelevant unless the SELECT is intentionally sorted, otherwise it will be random and thus my suggestion. But, yes you are right, not saying otherwise =)